# How to publish custom message on the TFS vNext build summary page?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, vnext

Here is a typical build summary page:

[image]

I would like to add a custom message somewhere on this page, preferably under its own title.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can custmoise Azure DevOps with extensions.

**What are extensions?**

Extensions are simple add-ons that can be used to customize and extend your DevOps experience with Azure DevOps Services. They are written with standard technologies - HTML, JavaScript, CSS - and can be developed using your preferred dev tools. They utilize our [RESTful API Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/) in order to easily interact with Azure DevOps Services and applications/services.

There is a big [marketplace](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiMxJq59sveAhXL34UKHePbBRIQFjAAegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketplace.visualstudio.com%2Fazuredevops&usg=AOvVaw3QrG4TICPpftBF3qgaaa-x), and in your case, you can write your own extension, find a tutorials [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=vsts).

You can find in [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer) an example how to extned the build summry page.